# Grabbing td element under web scraping in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Iam trying to catch the elements with a JS element as below

```
 <td align="right" valign="top" class="tabletext2" nowrap="nowrap"> <strong>Program Element Code(s):</strong></td>
```

Website is http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1227110&HistoricalAwards=false

The python script looks like as below

```
i=1300138;
i=str(i);
url= "http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID="+i+"&HistoricalAwards=false";
r = requests.get (url)
#webbrowser.open(url,new =new );
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
sp=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
gd=sp.findAll('td',{'class':'tabletext2'},nowrap="nowrap")
for item in gd:
    print item.text;           
    if item.text=="Program Element Code(s):":
        print item.contents;
```

But I cant get it to work . I need to grab the IDs in front of Program Reference Code(s)
Any help is appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Why can't you get it to work? Does it raise any exception?
Also, what does r.content means? What is `r`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to grab the next td after the correct `"class":"tabletext2"`:

```
url= "http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1227110&HistoricalAwards=false"
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(url)

tds = BeautifulSoup(r.content).find_all("td",{"class":"tabletext2"})

print([td.find_next("td").text.strip() for td in tds if td.text.startswith("Program Reference Code(s)")])

[u'131E, 113E, 8048, 7433']
```

Comment: No worries, you can probably do it using re to filter out the wrong tags but for a single value it won't make much difference.